# c# using 2d arrays for buttons

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array

[image]

the image above is how the program looks

the four top buttons have been put in a 2d array as follows

```
private Button[,] btns;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            btns = new Button[,] { { button2 , button1 },
                                   { button4 , button3 }};
        }
```

the four buttons have been initialized to

```
            foreach (var btn in btns)
            {
                btn.Enabled = false;
            }
```

and what i want to do is when you click the bottom two buttons each button in that row 
enables and a color is signed (red and blue in turn like a connect 4 game)

i have managed to solve half of the problem but when i click the row1 button it keeps enabling row 2 as well and when i click on row2 button it starts enabling from row one

how can i restrict each button to deal with the 2d array so it only enables the correct rows.

here is the full code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private Button[,] btns;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            btns = new Button[,] { { button2 , button1 },
                                   { button4 , button3 }};
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var btn in btns)
            {
                btn.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        int cc = 0;


        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (var btn in btns)
            {

                if (!btn.Enabled)
                {
                    btn.Enabled = true;

                    if (cc == 0)
                    {
                        cc = 1;
                        btn.BackColor = Color.Red;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cc = 0;
                        btn.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    }


                    return;
                }
            }
        }


        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (var btn in btns)
            {

                if (!btn.Enabled)
                {
                    btn.Enabled = true;

                    if (cc == 0)
                    {
                        cc = 1;
                        btn.BackColor = Color.Red;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cc = 0;
                        btn.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    }

                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SOLVED

This problem is solved and this is how i solved it:

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               Button[] row1 = new Button[] {button2, button1};
                foreach (var roww1 in row1)
                {

                    if (!roww1.Enabled)
                    {
                        roww1.Enabled = true;

                        if (cc == 0)
                        {
                            cc = 1;
                            roww1.BackColor = Color.Red;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cc = 0;
                            roww1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                        }


                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: @Kamil because i will extend it to a 7 by 6 board

Comment: That's a good solution. I guess button6_Click is identical except for the different row. You can factor out the repetition by using a method that takes the row array as an argument, and passing {button2, button1} in button5_Click and {button4, button3} in button6_Click.

Comment: I asked because i have one old project where i have 6x6 matrix. Array is nice idea to handle this... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a multidimensional array, you need to use a for loop instead of foreach to iterate through one row of the array at a time:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int col = 0; col < btns.GetLength(1); ++col)
   {
      var btn = btns[0, col];
   //snip
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int col = 0; col < btns.GetLength(1); ++col)
   {
      var btn = btns[1, col];
   //snip
}
```

Comment: i actually like this more than my way

Comment: how would you extend this program so that it detects diagonal vertical and horizontal matching colors with out using brute-force enum. similar to a connect 4 game

Comment: Now that's an interesting little puzzle, but I can only think of brute-force ways of doing it. You only need to test the buttons adjacent to the one that was last changed.