# 2 in a row game

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c# using 2d arrays for buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181258/c-sharp-using-2d-arrays-for-buttons)

I'm working on a game using a 2x2 board that will be extended to a 7x6.

I'm doing the winning detection at the moment, but I think I'm doing it the long way. There must be a much shorter way.

The winn

1. Horizontally
2. Vertically
3. Diagonally

Here's a pic of game board:

[image]

This is how I'm currently detecting winner

```
if (btns[0, col].BackColor.Equals(Color.Red) && btns[1, col].BackColor.Equals(Color.Red))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Red Win");
}

if (btns[0, col].BackColor.Equals(Color.Blue) && btns[1, col].BackColor.Equals(Color.Blue))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Blue Win");
}
```

This way seems like I have to list all combinations, and it would not be very ideal when I extend to 7x6.

Here is the whole code of the program

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private Button[,] btns;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            btns = new Button[,] { { button2 , button1 },
                                   { button4 , button3 }};
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var btn in btns)
            {
                btn.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        int cc = 0;


        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          // Button[] row1 = new Button[] {button2, button1};

            for (int col = 0; col < btns.GetLength(1); ++col)
            {
                var btn = btns[0, col];

                if (!btn.Enabled)
                {
                    btn.Enabled = true;

                    if (cc == 0)
                    {
                        cc = 1;
                        btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cc = 0;
                        btn.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    }

                    if (btns[0, col].BackColor.Equals(Color.Red) && btns[1, col].BackColor.Equals(Color.Red))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Red Win");
                    }

                    if (btns[0, col].BackColor.Equals(Color.Blue) && btns[1, col].BackColor.Equals(Color.Blue))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Blue Win");
                    }

                    return;
                }
            }
        }


        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Button[] row2 = new Button[] { button4, button3 };
            for (int col = 0; col < btns.GetLength(1); ++col)
            {
                var btn = btns[1, col];

                if (!btn.Enabled)
                {
                    btn.Enabled = true;

                    if (cc == 0)
                    {
                        cc = 1;
                        btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cc = 0;
                        btn.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    }

                    if (btns[1, col].BackColor.Equals(Color.Red) && btns[0, col].BackColor.Equals(Color.Red))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Red Win");
                    }

                    if (btns[1, col].BackColor.Equals(Color.Blue) && btns[0, col].BackColor.Equals(Color.Blue))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Blue Win");
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of other ways but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: your title should reflect the question which you're asking, not the project for which the answer applies to.

Comment: What is wrong with the answers in your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181258/c-sharp-using-2d-arrays-for-buttons

Comment: What are these "other ways" you have tried? What can't you "seem to get working"?

Comment: i cant seem to get it working with out using brute-force i have been trying to  use different loops but not happening man

Comment: @L.B it a different question now

Comment: @Tacit Can you summarize your question without making us guess or read a wall of text?

Comment: @L.B sorry man i thot i kept the text short i just want to detect 2 same colors next to eachother and output the result

Comment: @Tacit SO is for specific programming questions not for SO to build your app by adding a requirement at a time.

Comment: @Tacit  There's nothing wrong about asking frequent questions, but people generally want you to try and find the answers on your own before coming and asking a question, and you should also try to ask clear and specific questions, rather than the "can you guys code this for me" kind of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this answer is complicated and I'll get many downvotes but I couldn't resist solving this as optimal as possible. Try to inspect this code to the detail:

```
        int n; //dimension of the matrix
        Button [,] btns;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            n = 2;/*You should set here the dimension of your matix. I considered it nxn because of diagonals. If you want nxm matrix than the code is a little bit complicated but not too much*/
            btns = new Button[n, n];
            for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
               for(int j = 0; j<n; j++)
               {
                   Button btn = new Button();
                   btn.Location = new Point(i*20,j*40);
                   btn.Size = new Size(18,38);
                   btns[i,j] = btn;
                   this.Controls.Add(btn);
               }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int mainDiag = 0;
            int secDiag = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int [] cols = new int[n];
            int winner = 0; //no winner
            while(winner == 0 && i<n)
            {
                int row = 0;
                j = 0;
                while(j<n)
                {
                    if (btns[i, j].BackColor == Color.Blue)
                    {

                        if (i == j)
                            mainDiag++;//inrement main diagonal
                        if(i + j == n-1)
                            secDiag++;//increment second diagonal
                        row++; //increment row
                        cols[i]++; //increment column
                    }
                    else if (btns[i, j].BackColor == Color.Red)
                    {
                        if (i == j)
                            mainDiag--;
                        if(i + j == n-1)
                            secDiag--;
                        row--;
                        cols[i]++;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                if(row == n) //if row value == n whole row is blue and blue player wins
                    winner = 1;
                else if(row == -n)
                    winner = -1; //if row value == -n whole row is red and red player wins
                i++;
            }
            if(winner == 0)
            {
                if(mainDiag == n)
                    winner = 1; //similar for the diagonal
                else if(mainDiag == -n)
                    winner = -1; 
                else if(secDiag == n)
                    winner = 1;//similar for the second diagonal
                else if(secDiag == -n)
                    winner = -1;
                else
                {
                    i = 0;
                    while (winner == 0 && i < n)
                    {
                        if (cols[i] == n)
                            winner = 1; //i-th column is whole blue and blue player wins
                        else if (cols[i] == -n)
                            winner = -1; //i-th column is whole red and red player wins
                    }
                }
            }
            if (winner == 1)
                MessageBox.Show("Blue wins");
            else if(winner == -1)
                MessageBox.Show("Red wins");


        }
```

Comment: where are you including the buttons in the array @nick

Comment: I have updated it, it wasn't the main question, you should know how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As people have said in the comments, you'll probably want to use loops in order to do this.

I'm not going to go into a lot of detail here, but I'll describe some algorithms to accomplish your win condition detection.

**Algorithm 1:**
   For Each cell, detect whether that's part of a horizontal, vertical, or diagonal row.  The time complexity for this will be O(n^(3/2)).  You can account for duplicate checks if you want to but you don't have to.

**Algorithm 2:**
   Check All vertical rows, all horizontal rows, and all diagonal rows, and see if any win conditions lie upon those rows.  The time complexity for this method should be roughly O(n).  You could probably save a little bit of time by not checking diagonal  rows that aren't large enough to hold a win condition, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a really basic answer I would consider the following

Add each row into an array

Add each column into an array

For Each item in the array if they all equal a single colour then you have won

You may want to use a multi-dim array when you go to larger numbers (ie 6x6 grid)